# How To Update Hidden Field In Django Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to figure out the best approach to modifying a hidden django form field.  Or if it's even possible.  I had my HTML setup to accomplish this very task and it was working perfectly.  However, in order to prevent multiple submissions I had to change my HTML and now I am unable to figure out how to pass a value via an HTML button depending on what the user clicks on.

Previously, I had two buttons defined as outline below:

```
<button type="submit" class="button1" name="status" value="Saved"><h3 class="txtalgn4">Save</h3></button>

<button type="submit" class="button2" name="status" value="Submitted"><h3 class="txtalgn4">Submit</h3></button>
```

As stated above, this worked perfectly for the purpose of passing a value to an attribute for my model.  The value of status was saved as expected depending on which button the user clicked on.

Now I have updated the buttons to `type="button"` in response to this issue that I opened up today...[How To Prevent Double Submit With Form Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350851/how-to-prevent-double-submit-with-form-validation/54352510?noredirect=1#comment95521614_54352510)

I tried using the following code:

```
<button type="button" class="button1" name="status" value="Saved"><h3 class="txtalgn4">Save</h3></button>

<button type="button" class="button2" name="status" value="Submitted"><h3 class="txtalgn4">Submit</h3></button>
```

And then I also changed the status field to `{{ status.as_hidden }}` in my HTML to get the value.  This only works if I hardcode the status value in my database structure.  I need to be able to get this value dynamically depending on what the user clicks.  Is JQuery with Ajax the right approach for this?  Is there some simple way to modify the hidden field depending on which button the user clicks?

Is there some better way to go about trying to get this field in a hidden manner?  As stated above the HTML way with `type="submit"` worked perfectly, but caused problems when I was trying to prevent the user from double submitting the form.  As in all things programming I solved one problem and created another.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: How is `type="button"` hide your input it should be `type="hidden"` instead and yes you need ajax for that.

Comment: @Ahtisham Thanks for the input.  Kind of.  Yes if I change type="button" to type="hidden" and remove my hidden field it works for the save.  If I do the same for the submit, it works but breaks the logic that I've put in place to prevent the double submission.  I'm trying to achieve both, prevent double submission and pass dynamic hidden value depending on which button the user clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep using two submit buttons like you were. But instead of disabling the buttons, you disable the whole form from submitting if once submitted.

First, give your form a unique html ID.

```
<form id="myform">
    ...
</form>

<!-- JS code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('submitted')) {
        // prevent submission
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    $(this).addClass('submitted');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You made my week!   Thank you so much.  Works awesome.